# What is the proper meaning of travesty?

Tags: word-usage

Merriam Webster dictionaries define travesty as:
a debased, distorted, or grossly inferior imitation.
And among the examples of travesty, was a sentence which was:
It is a travesty and a tragedy that so many people would be denied the right to vote.
So, what the denial of right to vote is imitation of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the right to vote was “debased” ie while they gave the “right”, they removed the reason for the vote making it no longer effective.

The three examples do not all have to be used or relevant.